# How to prevent the usage of try catch with suspendCancellableCoroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines, android-mvp

I have made a corouting that calls an asynchronous method in my interactor, the thing is that when the continuation block gets executed, I dont want to use a try catch block since I think is not the right way to do this.

### Presenter

```
  override fun signInWithCoroutines(email: String, password: String) {

        launch {
            view?.showProgress()
            try{
                signInInteractor.signInWithCoroutinesTest(email,password)
            }catch(e FirebaseLoginException){  ---> want to know if there is another way to do this
                view.showError(e.getMessage())

            }

            view?.hideProgress()
            view?.navigateToMain()
        }

    }
```

### SignInInteractor

```
override suspend fun signInWithCoroutinesTest(email: String, password: String): Unit = suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance()?.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)?.addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                continuation.resume(Unit)
            } else {
                continuation.resumeWithException(FirebaseLoginException("Error while login in, try again")
            }
        }
    }
```

### Question

Is there another way to catch the continuation resume and the exception in my presenter from my interactor ?

I have readed that the try catch block is an anti pattern to work with coroutines

https://proandroiddev.com/kotlin-coroutines-patterns-anti-patterns-f9d12984c68e

> If async block may throw exception don’t rely on wrapping it with
>   try/catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using an `async` block, so try catch is exactly what you should be using to wrap exceptions called by a `suspend` method.

Comment: Thanks ian, if there are 1 more asyncmethod inside my **signInWithCoroutinesTest**, for example, after **if(it.isSuccefull)** , should I also add try catch inside my interactor to wait for the other method ? doing that will be likely the same as callback hells, thanks

Comment: If you're using `suspend` methods throughout, then exceptions are handled just as if they were blocking methods - you can catch them at whatever level is appropriate.